# How best to archive many JPEG files containing significant redundancy across their scenes?

Tags: image-compression, archiving

Archives of JPEG files don't compress well, ostensibly because each JPEG is already highly compressed.  However, when there is much redundancy between images (e.g., archived stills from a stationary camera), and the number of files is large (think thousands or more), there comes a point when failure to exploit the redundancies makes JPEG seem dramatically inefficient for files to be stored in archives.

What approach and archive format would give the best compression of JPEG files?